# Read Whatsapp messages using Selenium and .NET

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, whatsapp

I found a lot of examples in Internet how to use Selenium to send WhatsApp messages (via WA Web).  Majority of examples are in Py, but found also some in C# (Im using)

Did some test development and this seems to work.

But for my project I need opposite functionality: *reading in/out messages*  (for backup purposes).
I dont really need sending msgs...

Can someone please advise if this is doable with Selenium / how to do that?
Any .NET code examples / tips will be highly appreciated :)

Comment: Please show us what have you tried, what specific problems faced etc.

Comment: for example this one: https://www.craftedforeveryone.com/whatsapp-send-api-or-click-to-chat-automation-using-selenium-and-c-sharp/  

I mentioned my problem - I know how to send but not to read msgs (webhooks)

Answer (score 1):

you can use [wppconnect wa-js](https://github.com/wppconnect-team/wa-js)

uer execute javascript